# Error loading Python lib while checking AWS version ( during configuration of AWS CLI)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terminal, command-line-interface

I'm trying to install AWS CLI in my MacOS using the AWS [documention for MacOS- Command line- current user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html).

Since I'm getting an error while executing the below (since I don't have admin privileges),

```
sudo ln -s /folder/installed/aws-cli/aws /usr/local/bin/aws
sudo ln -s /folder/installed/aws-cli/aws_completer /usr/local/bin/aws_completer
```

so I move the AWS binary to a bin directory in your home directory, and add that to your PATH variable, eg

```
mkdir ~/bin

cp /Users/ssur/aws-cli/aws ~/bin/aws
```

and then put ~/bin in your path adding this line in ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Users/ssur/bin:$PATH"
```

After executing all of this in Terminal, I run the below command:

`% aws --version`

and I  get an error as shown below:

```
[14290] Error loading Python lib '/Users/ssur/bin/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/ssur/bin/Python, 0x000A): tried: '/Users/ssur/bin/Python' (no such file)
```

Could you kindly help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnxwT.png)

On executing the final command(% aws --version), I was expecting something maybe like:
`aws-cli/2.9.19 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/23.1.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off`

Comment: What happens when you type in python3 --version or python --version(older macs)?

"which python3" or "which python" should give your python location. Does that match "/Users/ssur/bin/Python"? In my mac it shows up at "/usr/bin/python3"

Comment: In my mac terminal i get this result:

~ % pwd 
/Users/ssur

-------
 ~ % python3 --version 
Python 3.11.2

--------
 ~ % python --version 
Python 3.9.6

----------
 ~ % which python 
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3

------

 ~ % which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3

Answer (score 0):

The 'Python' file is located in the installation directory that you chose for the aws-cli.

My recommendation is not to symlink the 'aws' and 'aws_completer' applications as shown in the documentation, but instead add the installation directory to your PATH, after which the error will go away.   There may be other ways to solve this, but this approach works for me.